# CrystalReport does not show correct data

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, crystal-reports

i'm using crystal report with visual studio 2017 but i'v a problem 
the crystal report does not show the correct data it is always return all records in database

i'm using the following to get the data from the database

```
public static List<Package> GetPalletReport(int Id)
    {
        using (ProjectEntities db = new ProjectEntities())
        {
            List<Package> packages = new List<Package>();
            Package _p = 
            db.Packages.Include(p => p.Alloy)
                .Include(p => p.Temper)
                .Include(p => p.PaintType1)
                .Include(p => p.BackCoat)
                .SingleOrDefault(p => p.PackageId == Id);
            for(int i=0; i<_p.NumberOfLabels; i++)
            {
                packages.Add(_p);
            }
            return packages;
        }
    }
```

an i load it to crystal report as following:

```
 public ActionResult PrintReport(int Id)
    {
        ProjectEntities db = new ProjectEntities();
        ReportDocument rd = new ReportDocument();
        rd.Load(Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Reports"), "PalletReport.rpt"));
        var test = ReportingManager.GetPalletReport(Id);
        rd.SetDataSource(test);
        Response.Buffer = false;
        Response.ClearContent();
        Response.ClearHeaders();
        try
        {
            Random n = new Random(100);
            int x = n.Next();
            Stream stram = rd.ExportToStream(CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat);
            stram.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            return File(stram, "application/pdf", "Document" + x + ".pdf");
        }
        catch (Exception f)
        {

        }
        return View();
    }
```

Comment: Is `GetPalletReport` returning all records in the `List<Package>`, or is the Crystal Report "ignoring" it when you set the data source?

Comment: thanks @Frank Alvaro, it is ignoring it